# Using dplyr, across(), where() and if_else() functions to replace NA by a number

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my datafrmae:

```
library(mlbench)
data(BreastCancer)

df_1<-BreastCancer
```

I did some modifications and appears "Na"'s on "Bare.nuclei" column:

```
df_1<-df_1 %>% mutate(across(where(~is.factor(.x)),as.numeric))
```

I am learning how to use `across()`, `where()` and `ifelse()` functions to replace these NA's by `0` .

```
df_1 %>% mutate(across(where(~ is.numeric(.x)), if_else(is.na(.x,0,.x))))
```

What am I doing wrong?

The idea here is to go `across` `where` the columns are `numerics`, and if on these columns I have `Nas` I will replace by `111`, otherwhise mantain x.

Comment: `df_1 %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~if_else(is.na(.x),0,.x)))`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the `tidyr::replace_na()` function instead of `if_else`.

```
df_1 %>% mutate(across(where(~ is.numeric(.x)), function(x){replace_na(x, 0)}))
```